# Error when compiling a static library using Swift "unknown option character `X' in: -Xlinker"

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

Seeing this error when adding a swift file for compilation into a static library. using XCode 6.0 (6A215l)

Full libtool error:

`Libtool DerivedData/SwiftTest/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libstatic.a normal i386
    cd /Users/al/dev/ios/SwiftTest2
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only i386 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk -L/Users/al/dev/ios/SwiftTest2/DerivedData/SwiftTest/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/al/dev/ios/SwiftTest2/DerivedData/SwiftTest/Build/Intermediates/SwiftTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/static.build/Objects-normal/i386/static.LinkFileList -ObjC -L/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -force_load -Xlinker /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a -Xlinker -sectalign -Xlinker __SWIFT -Xlinker __ast -Xlinker 4 -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __SWIFT -Xlinker __ast -Xlinker /Users/al/dev/ios/SwiftTest2/DerivedData/SwiftTest/Build/Intermediates/SwiftTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/static.build/Objects-normal/i386/static.swiftmodule -o /Users/al/dev/ios/SwiftTest2/DerivedData/SwiftTest/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libstatic.a`

I've create a sample project here, the error happens in a completly fresh project: https://github.com/amleszk/SwiftTest/tree/cd94ca21d817fed336b1a3bfc774a13608e0d1ca

To reproduce checkout the project and build the SwiftTest target, which has a dependency on the static library. Any help appreciated

Comment: Show the complete build line in your question.

Comment: Isn't that code in Obj C? I didn't see any swift code in there. Did I miss it?

Comment: Any luck with this? I tried the same thing: create a static lib and start writing in Swift but I'm getting the same error

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Update:** It seems like the official release of Xcode 6 still has that same issue.

From the xcode 6 beta 2 release notes:

> It is not possible to build static libraries which contain Swift code in this release

Comment: I also getting this error using Xcode6-beta6. Any update on this? Thanks.

Comment: Still getting this error in Pre-released Xcode6

Comment: Still getting this with Xcode 6.1 Beta, and the Xcode 6.0.1 GM

Comment: Same problem. Note that unit tests build fine, just the static library itself doesn't. I'm going to try a Swift framework instead and see how that works out.

Comment: @femot can you update your answer to include that its not working in the official release of Xcode 6 as well

Comment: also got this problem in Xcode 6.1 release, any workaround?

Comment: Same story for 6.1.1.

Comment: Even for 6.3.1. This is not good.

Comment: 6.4 beta still not working - created a framework instead of a static library.

Comment: with swift we can't create static library the only would be creating a framework.so framework is basically collection of static and dynamic libraries but dynamic library we shouldn't use as dynamic linking is opposed to apple rules.so swift project is turned into framework it has to contain static library its quite contradicting.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. This is hook, but it works.
You should do this as root.

1. Go to default toolchain bin directory

   `cd $(xcode-select -p)/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin`
2. Rename current libtool to old_libtool

   `mv libtool old_libtool`
3. Create new libtool

   `touch libtool && chmod +x libtool`
4. Insert current script as content of new libtool

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python
   import os
   import subprocess
   import sys
   args=[]
   for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
       if arg != '-Xlinker' and arg != '-add_ast_path' and not arg.endswith('swiftmodule'):
           args.append(arg)
   args.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'old_libtool'))
   subprocess.check_call(args)
   ```
5. Compile.

Comment: Could you explain in better detail why you have to do this and what the script does?

Comment: This didn't work for me. Should I make something different, since this answer is old?